# why no sort(v) in C++?

Tags: c++, stl

I always wondered why there is no

```
sort(v);// same as std::sort(v.begin(),v.end())
```

If I recall correctly long time ago I saw a boostcon clip where speaker said that concepts are required for this, but I dont see why.
BTW I tried this (in VS 11) and it works niceli from what I can see.

```
template <typename Container>
void sortfx(Container& c)
{
    std::sort(c.begin(),c.end());
}
int main()
{

    std::vector<double> v;
    //std::list<double> v; this causes compile errors
    v.push_back(1701);
    v.push_back(1729);
    v.push_back(74656);
    v.push_back(2063);
    sortfx(v);
    assert(std::is_sorted(begin(v),end(v)));

}
```

EDIT:
Bjarne himself explains the concepts, with sort as an example :)
https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2080042&WT.rss_f=Article&WT.rss_a=An%20Interview%20with%20Bjarne%20Stroustrup&WT.rss_ev=a

Comment: Guess they just figured it's not worth adding when you can just take the time to write two arguments, or your own, or that the masses wouldn't get a lot of use out of it. It's one of those personal library additions that could work well for some people. Besides, if they added `sort` for the whole container, they would probably have to add others as well.

Comment: You could implement it. But what if you want to sort a built-in array? You should use SFINAE or some other mechanism to achieve the same. It's just more code without reason. `std::sort(c.begin(),c.end());` is short enough.

Comment: @mfontanini And other people would think that always specifying the used comparator is also "short enough", but we still don't have to. I agree that it's an annoying omission, because really 99% of the time we want to sort the whole container.

Comment: @mfontanini:  C++11 makes this easy too:  `using std::begin; using std::end; std::sort(begin(c), end(c));`  Nonmember functions FTW!

Comment: @JamesMcNellis some more tricks like this and we'll be back in C again...

Comment: If you want algorithms that work like this, you can use [boost::range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/range/doc/html/index.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not the `std::sort(v)` -> `std::sort(v.begin(), v.end())` expansion that would need concepts, but the alternate sort function taking an additional parameter for the comparison - `std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), compare)`.

If you have a call `std::sort(v, compare)`, the implementation *would* need concepts to distinguish it from `std::sort(start, end)` for a non-container.

The `<algorithm>` header is full of templates with this kind of problem.

Comment: Actually having both `sort(v, compare)` and `sort(start, end)` would work just fine in most cases ([example](http://ideone.com/7QTf44)). As commented [there](http://herbsutter.com/2011/10/07/why-no-container-based-algorithms/#comment-3622), a problem would only arise if the container itself were used as a comparator, in which case you would get an horrible multi-error message pointing to the deep implementation of the overload taking two iterators ([simplified example](http://ideone.com/DR5JN5), to be compared with [the same code with last line commented](http://ideone.com/N4TfMa)).

Answer (score 5):

From [Learning Standard C++ as a New Language (PDF)](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/new_learning.pdf) Stroustrup, C/C++ Users Journal. pp 43-54. May 1999:

> Plain sort(v) would have been simpler in this case, but sometimes we want to sort part of a
>   container so it’s more general to specify the beginning and end of what we want to sort.

That makes sense to me. It's trivial to create a wrapper, as you've demonstrated, and it's not terribly cumbersome to use without a wrapper. Having a second `sort()` that took the Container just doesn't seem worth it.

Answer (score 3):

`<algorithm>` functions don't work on container directly. They only interacts with iterators, without any context knowledge of the container. I see no harm if you use a short full range sort notation for you own purpose, but you have to assume the object have begin / end interface, which also happen to be bidirectional iterators.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing about this that requires concepts. Ranges are not any more complex than iterators really.

Answer (score 1):

What if you only wanted to sort a subset of the container?

I almost posted a similar question recently about why `for_each` isn't a member function of `Container` instead of being standalone. i.e. `v.for_each([&sum] (int i) { sum += i; });`

Comment: I don't think there's ever been a time where i just wanted to sort *part* of a container.

Comment: Nor I, but maybe someone somewhere has

Comment: I have used a partial sort to find the median for some silly statistics homework.

Comment: @cHao I guess something like get top 100

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: You'd still have to sort the whole collection before you'd know the top 100.  Unless you mean the *first* 100, in which case you'd trim the collection and then sort the whole thing if you wanted them sorted.

Comment: oh cra*, im sleepy :) i was talking about partial sort, you are talking about sorting part of the container. :)

Answer (score 0):

Concepts aren't *required* for this -- but (as they were proposed during C++11 standardization) they would have made it fairly easy to implement this.

As it stands right now, you *could* do this by providing a couple of extra overloads (or possibly explicit specializations) for `std::sort`. The problem, of course, is that `std::sort` isn't the only algorithm, so you'd undoubtedly want to do the same for lots of other algorithms as well (nearly all of them, most likely).

Concepts (specifically, concept maps, if memory serves) would have provided a fairly clean way to provide (equivalents of) all those overloads in a relatively centralized way, so you'd have all those adapters in one place instead of N places (one for each algorithm). Better still, as long as they conformed to the normal conventions, it would work for other algorithms as well.

Quite a few people currently believe ranges are the way this should be handled -- that algorithms should operate on ranges, and any container should define a range (but there should be other ways to define ranges as well). While this is probably good as a general idea, it appears (at least to me) that there's a fair amount of disagreement over the precise details of what should constitute a range, how they should be defined, etc.

If you really want to explore this, Boost already has a [range library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) that includes range-based versions of most of the standard algorithms (and a number of others as well). At least if memory serves, this includes some adapters to create a range from a container, so things like `sort(c)` will work without your having to explicitly specify a range or iterators.