# Why isn't an overload provided in standard library functions with iterator parameters?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, iterator, range

There are lots of functions in the standard library that are structured like this:

```
std::foo(begin(x), end(x), bar);
```

What bothers me about this is that 99% of the time, the arguments are begin and end. Why don't these functions all have overloads that would surely be used more often like:

```
std::foo(x, bar);
```

Is it a language or design limitation or is it an oversight? Thanks.

Comment: What's stopping you from writing such a method yourself? The standard library gives you the generic version -- if you want a convenience overload, indulge yourself.

Comment: You can already do this with Boost.Range, but the standard might be getting actual ranges sometime before too long.

Comment: A lot of what is already in boost and many libraries should have been in the standard a long time ago.. Some of these conveniences is why people use Java and C#.. because .Net and the Java library already provides ease of use functions.. For example, loading images and what not.. No need for external libraries or writing wrappers.. Yes OP, yes they could have templated a lot of them differently and made things easy.. but I don't think anyone is going to be able to tell you `why` without their opinion being the answer or excuses for the standard being the way it is.. C++ is my fave lang still..

Comment: I can't speak for the standards committee, but my guess is that those overloads are omitted because they are trivial to implement by the user of the standard library and perhaps in their opinion adding them all would clutter the interface.

Comment: Anyway OP, the best opinion and excuse that I can come up with is that it's backward compatibility with C style arrays.. For some of those functions you can pass pointers to the beginning and end of the array.. Whereas if it was templated differently, and accessed container.begin and container.end, C-style arrays may not work with it.. example: `std::min(&CArray[0], &CArray[some_size]);`

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames, It could still use `std::begin` and `std::end` and work fine on both containers and arrays.

Comment: I asked that and it was answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174501/why-no-sortv-in-c/11176568#11176568

Comment: Personal opinion: the entire STL design of using two items (begin, end) to represent a range is extremely inconvenient and limiting. I have devised and implemented the concept of "traversor" as an alternative to iterators, which roughly represents a (begin, end) pair and has `operator bool` to indicate termination. It is thus trivial to distinguish between sequence (array) versions and traversor versions of functions. This also enables infinite sequences (defined by a function) or variadic sequence/traversor functions (like applying an n-ary function to each element of n sequences/ranges).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at Herb Sutter's old column [**"Why no container-based algorithms?"**](http://herbsutter.com/2011/10/07/why-no-container-based-algorithms/)

The problem is that if you already have e.g.

```
template<class Iter>             std::sort(Iter, Iter)       // (1)
template<class Iter, class Pred> std::sort(Iter, Iter, Pred) // (2)
```

then introducing

```
template<class Container>             std::sort(Container)       // (3)
template<class Container, class Pred> std::sort(Container, Pred) // (4)
```

gives C++98 containers a hard time distinguishing (1) from (4): just pass an `iterator` and a `const_iterator` to `sort()` and overload resolution could match (4) instead of (1).

With C++11 and SFINAE it should be possible to work around most of these issues, but a full rewrite will probably have to wait until [**Concepts**](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/concepts) and [**Ranges**](http://www.open-std.org/mailman/listinfo/ranges) have been fully worked out by the C++ Standards Committee.